# Date between with calculation in SQL

Tags: sql, tableau-api

I need help with SQL and Tableau for same issue. I need to execute the calculation below:

```
processed date = dateinticated > (dateintiated-7days)
```

The result needs to be in date format for it to work in table and filter.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT col1, col2, date
FROM table
WHERE date > somedate - INTERVAL '1 week';
```

The important take away from this answer is the INTERVAL syntax part. Couldn't write the specific query you'd use as I'm lacking an example of your data scheme.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ‘-‘ operator to subtract an integer number of days from a date, as in [Some Date] - 7 (the integer literal is assumed to be in units of days) The ‘+’ operator works similarly.

To adjust a date by different units such as weeks, months, years, use the DATEADD() function, as in DateAdd(‘week’, -1, [Some Date]) to subtract one week from [Some Date]